# C# min max value on DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have an DataGridView with quotas in it.

I wanna find the smallest quota and color its font with red and the max quota to color its font with green.

Am drawing an custom DataGrid component with transparent background on a UserControl.

Comment: Have you tried anything that failed to do your desired work? Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) guide to get a better idea on how does Stackoverflow system work, and then you'd get better help and even better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "DataBindingComplete" event. This will do the trick.

```
private void qoutaGrid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int min = qoutaGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Min(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["MyProperty"].Value));
        int max = qoutaGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["MyProperty"].Value));

        for (int i = 0; i < qoutaGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(qoutaGrid.Rows[i].Cells["MyProperty"].Value);
            if (value == min)
            {
                qoutaGrid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (value == max)
            {
                qoutaGrid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
    }
```

Let say your desired number is stored in MyProperty. You can get minimum and maximum of the bound datasource. Then you can compare other values with min and max in order to set the fore color of the cell using DefaultCellStyle.

Comment: Column named MyProperty cannot be found.
Parameter name: columnName , it has 6 columns and 6 rows.. is not about one column, i wanna find the minimal of all columns and rows and the maximal of all columns and rows.

Comment: @MelaminBerati This "MyProperty" word is just an example because I didn't know the real name of the column!! you must use the name of that quota column data you mentioned.

Comment: There are 6 columns and are named as following QUOTA1, QUOTA2, QUOTA3,QUOTA4,QUOTA5,QUOTA6